# What does $(p,\alpha)(q,\beta)$ mean?

Tags: notation, vectors

I was studying and reading about Advanced Computer Vision, in particular the book *Guide to 3D Vision Computation* and I encountered the following equation:

$$ A_{k\lambda}^{(\alpha)} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^4 (x_{\alpha k},u_{ik})(x_{\alpha \lambda},u_{i \lambda})}{||x_{\alpha k}|| ||x_{\alpha \lambda}||}$$

I cannot understand what the 2 vectors separated by commas in parenthesis that we can see twice in the numerator mean. Is it a concatenation? Because there is little more I can think about.

Comment: Can be scalar product.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if you tell us what the notations means. What are all these variables ?

Comment: @Lelouch all the $x_\alpha$ and $u_i$ are vectors.